# Is there an emacs for Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, emacs

How can I install emacs on Xubuntu , the command:

```
sudo apt-get install emacs
```

doesn't work

Comment: to clarify `sudo apt-get install emacs` does what?  what terminal output do you see?  Which version of xubuntu are you using?

Comment: It doesn't appear if i write sudo apt-get install e
and then with tab there is no emacs

Comment: Try pressing tab twice in rapid succession. It will ask you something like "Display all 564 possibilities? (y or n)". Try writing 'sudo apt-get install emac' and then press tab.

Comment: didn't work, never mind switched to UBUNTU

Comment: Apparently you did not have tab completion enabled for `apt-get`.  You should be able to fix that with `sudo apt-get install bash-completion`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to find out is navigate to the following URL in a browser:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/

try your search there, of course you will need to select the appropriate version your using. This should give you a brief answer if the package is included for your version of ubuntu.

Another easy way is to search on your local system if emacs is available in the PPA

- Open a command line terminal by issuing Ctrl-Alt-T or searching for terminal in the Dash and type

  ```
           #sudo apt-get update
           #apt-cache search emacs
  ```

This will search all of the packages in the ppa for the words emacs in the title.

According to my response theres a few packages available.

```
emacs - The GNU Emacs editor (metapackage)
emacs-goodies-el - Miscellaneous add-ons for Emacs
emacs23 - The GNU Emacs editor (with GTK+ user interface)
emacs23-bin-common - The GNU Emacs editor's shared, architecture dependent files
emacs23-common - The GNU Emacs editor's shared, architecture independent infrastructure
emacs23-el - GNU Emacs LISP (.el) files
emacs23-nox - The GNU Emacs editor (without X support)
```

So essentially you could try to

```
#sudo apt-get install
```

any of the above packages.

Comment: I like to use aptitude to search for packages, although it will get you pretty much the same result.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install emacs
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Xubuntu includes the Synaptic Package Manager by default. Please go to the menu, System, Synaptic Package Manager, and search on EMACS. It will guide you to the correct applications.